# kafka-cassandra-sink error for json data insertion in cassandra

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect, cassandra-3.0

I am using kafka connect 1.0.0 with kafka version 1.0 for my kafka-cassandra-sink.created a test topic IndiaDataEngineerTest and a cassandra table  indiatest having structure as

```
IndiaTest (
    datetime timeuuid, 
    city text, 
    phone_number text,
    PRIMARY KEY (datetime,phone_number)
);
```

In my topic data is written as json from a producer as below:

```
{"datetime":"c8ba2390-4783-11e8-af08-d9271f3c3d48","city":"Santa Monica","phone_number":"+131000000001"}
{"datetime":"42485b20-44f3-11e8-b543-77b9a2d3bc92","city":"Anaheim","phone_number":"+131000000002"}
{"datetime":"53b5c980-41c7-11e8-8689-7983010e6437","city":"Not Found","phone_number":"+131000000004"}
{"datetime":"d43b3860-419a-11e8-a2eb-59f9c7b79f07","city":"Anaheim","phone_number":"+131000000003"}
```

i am tryig to write above data in my cassandra table using below sink prop as below:

```
{

"name": "cassandra-sink",
"config": {
"tasks.max":"1",
"connector.class":"com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector",
    "topics":"IndiaDataEngineerTest",
    "connect.cassandra.contact.points": "www.abc.com",
    "connect.cassandra.port": 9042,
    "connect.cassandra.username": "jay",
    "connect.cassandra.password": "jaytest",
    "connect.cassandra.key.space": "message",
    "connect.cassandra.kcql":"INSERT INTO IndiaTest SELECT datetime,city,phone_number FROM IndiaDataEngineerTest"
    }
}
```

Now after starting connect as soon I send the config file following error encountered.

```
[2018-11-13 01:39:55,166] INFO Preparing statements for IndiaDataEngineerTest->IndiaTest (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter:83)
[2018-11-13 01:39:55,178] ERROR Encountered error line 1:33 missing "(" at (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter:62)
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:33 missing "(" at missing at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:104)
    at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:108)
    at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:104)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
```

Can anyone help me out or suggest what went wrong...??
Advance thanks.

Comment: `at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError` seems to be an internal problem with the DataStax driver, not Kafka Connect, perhaps you can create an issue at https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor/issues ?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks i have highlighted the issue.

Comment: Where are you running Kafka Connect? On its own machine? Docker? Is it possible that the classpath is colliding with something else?

Comment: @cricket_007 I was running Kafka connect on differenent server machine other than kafka and zookeper.

Comment: And other than Cassandra?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. cassandra cluster is also on different server machine.

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer below rather than as a comment. Also, Datastax just released their own Cassandra connector, which you may try

Comment: @cricket_007 Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved as I am not using correct version of Cassandra. For kafka connect 1.0.0 with kafka version 1.0 , it require Cassandra version 3.0.9 or above.